# i want only that child which strickly follow X+Y+Z=9 if not follow than doing process one more time with other element,

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

```
wappedcolumns = [7 8];

child = parent;

swapoddeven = reshape([2:2:size(parent, 1); 1:2:size(parent, 1)], 1, ]); 

child(swapoddeven, swappedcolumns) = child(1:size(parent, 1),swappedcolumns)
```

after this i process i got child matrix

```
 x     y     z
 1     2     6 =9 valid
 6     2     1 =9 valid
 2     1     4 =7 not valid
 2     1     1 =4 not valid
 6     2     8 =16 not valid
 1     7     8 =16 not valid
```

i want only that child which strickly follow `X+Y+Z=9` if not follow than doing process one more time with other element,

my code uptill now... i want to find minumum value of `[(X(-0.33).^2+(Y-0.33).^2+(Z-0.33).^2]` this function where `X+Y+Z=9` with genetic algorithm